# SailsJS populating attributes sent via socket publishUpdate

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js, waterline

I am using the inbuilt socket capabilities of SailsJS which have been working great. Now I've come across a hurdle that I can't find any info on.

My model is set-up to populate some of the attributes using waterline model associations for example:

```
getAll: function() {
        return Issue.find()
        .sort('createdAt DESC')
        .populate('author')
        .populate('group')
        .populate('tags')
        .then(function (models) {
            return [models];
        });
    },
```

This is working fine when calling this method through the API. However in the case where an update is made via a `put` and `Issue.publishUpdate(id, update);` is called, the attributes are then sent un-populated to subscribed clients. This is not the behaviour I had expected as `publishCreate`, on the otherhand, sends populated results.

To workaround the hurdle I could manually populate the attributes before sending the publishUpdate, however this doesn't seem like the right way to do it with Sails? So before I go that route I would be interested to hear anyone else's thoughts or experience.

*Sails v0.10.1*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blueprint API calls publishUpdate, but it is actually a standalone method that can be used anywhere:

http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub/publishUpdate.html

publishUpdate broadcasts the data that you pass in, so to broadcast populated data, you'll need to pass it in.